Windows attempts to run a Python version which I uninstalled
I am a total beginner to all of this so apologies if this seems obvious or simple:
A couple of years ago I played around with learning python and installed anaconda. I didn't have the time to learn at that point so I ended up uninstalling and deleting anaconda, python, etc from my laptop.
I am now ready t start learning python, so today I installed the latest version through python.org and also jupyter notebook.
All seems to have intalled as expected.
However, when I go to command prompt and try to open jupyter notebook I receive the following error:
C:\Users\marck>jupyter-notebook
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Users\marck\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

From my basic understanding it seems to be refering to the old version of python I had previously installed (but have since deleted). I have follwed these paths above and can see there are still folders and files present.
Any ideas on how to completely wipe all historic files and start afresh would be much appreciated.

I went trough the same process once and I ended up deleting all files and folders with regards to Python (i.e. the \Users\marck\AppData\Roaming\Python directory) and then reinstalled Python from scratch. It's not the cleanest solution but at least it worked. Using VScode then made it easier to get a running setup for the notebooks.

Please [edit] to reveal what exactly you installed and where. Where is your new Python installed? What's the output of whereis jupyter-notebook? See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

I am unfamiliar with windows, but I think when you enter python, it is a dead alias to the old .exe. You have to locate your new .exe and either run it directly or overwrite the alias
